# CSS: Performance wise, better to use calc or position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div with fixed height. Inside two divs, the top height: 50px and the other one must fill the empty space but allowing internal scroll.

Now I have two options:

```
#up{
    height: 50px;
}

#down{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

or:

```
#up{
    height: 50px;
}

#down{
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

If I have many of these cases inside my window, which one is the best to use  performance wise?

[**This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh2dzo9/)

ps. **I don't care about old browser support**.

Comment: the first, since you're comparing also consider using translate

Comment: Your two examples don't have the same behaviour.

Comment: @MrLister what do you mean? I added a fiddle

Comment: @kiwi1342 Yes, and you had to change the css for the absolutely positioned one, because it wouldn't behave the same as the other one...

Comment: @kiwi1342 in addition, any html content added after `#down1` in the code would be positioned directly below `.up` (i.e. hidden behind `#down1`), while content after `#down2` would be positioned below it. ([New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3Lh2dzo9/1/))

Comment: There isn't really a noteable difference performance-wise (its CSS after all), but using calc surely is a better practice than using position:absolute and breaking the flow of the html.

Answer (score 2):

I would always work with `calc` option. Both could look the same but they are not.

When you use `position:absolute` You are taking the container `#down` out of the html flow.

This means that if anytime you are going to add more stuff to your project, You will have many problems positioning them.

As an example, if you want to add another container below `#down` (a footer maybe), in your first option it will be placed overlapping `#down` container right below your header. In the second option it will be placed where you want it.

Comment: Its also terrible for responsiveness. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to fill the space would be to use `flexbox`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}

#up {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

#down {
  background: orange;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="up">
    up
  </div>
  <div id="down">
    down
  </div>
</div>
```